# How to set up ipv6 home routing?

Tags: iptables, ip, routing, ipv6

I've got a IPv4 only ISP and get a public IPv4 address from them. On my router, a Linux machine, I've setup a 6in4 tunnel using a tunnel provider. So I now have a tunnel interface (point-to-point) with a Global scope IPv6 address: 2001:abcd:abcd::2/64. As I understand it, the whole /64 block is routed to me, i.e., I can freely define any address in that block (::3, ::4, etc). From my router, I can reach IPv6 sevices just fine (ping6 works, traceroute6 works). The router does NAT for my LAN. Now I want to route one machine inside my LAN using IPv6 as well, assigning it ::3.

The current setup:

eth0.123: DHCP from public Internet on VLAN 123

eth1: 192.168.1.1 + IPv6 link local

tun6: 2001:abcd:abcd::2/64

I've tried adding 2001:abcd:abcd::3/64 to the interface IP of my LAN machine, but it cannot ping 2001:abcd:abcd::2/64. Therefore, I fail to setup my IPv6 network even before I come to the routing part.

How do I have to configure the network interfaces so my router can talk to my local machine using IPv6 and then how do I allow routing of IPv6 traffic to the Internet?

Comment: Use `ip -6 route` and `ip get 2001:abcd:abcd::2` on your LAN machine to test if the routing is correct. If not, you can configure all of that manually; but usually you'd run `radvd` on your router (correctly configured), and let it advertise your prefix to the rest of the LAN. The LAN machines can then configure themselves automatically via SLAAC (stateless IPv6 autoconf).

Comment: You're meant to use the other routed netblock the tunnel provider should have given you. The initial /64 is only for the point to point connection.